# Moving firefox profile kills drm?

Tags: firefox, spotify, drm

I wanted to put my firefox profile to a different location.

**Moving-Procedure**: So i copied the profile dir to the new location and started `fiefox -P` and created a new profile (after deleting the old name) on which I selected the new location of the directory.

Everything was working fine - except when I noticed that DRM does not work: e.g. spotify or amazon prime or .... . I deactivated and reactivated (restarted firefox always after doing each) drm support in settings, I even did the same with widevine in plugins. Didn't do anything, spotify, amazon still does not work.

So I made the same moving-procedure again back to the origin location.. and hey it works again.

*Question*: Is it not possible to **use the profile directory in some other place *and* use drm?** And why is that? Maybe I have to change a directory link refering to widevine?

**Edit**: The problem only occurs if the profile directory is *not* on `c:` but on another drive.

**Edit 2:** The problem is solved for spotify, when it is on `c:` (how to fix this on other drives?), but: amazon prime doesn't work even then (with firefox program itself on other drive than c:). Maybe this is something because of widevine (i cleaned firefox in about:support - didn't help)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to create a new profile, only move it.  If you create a new one, it is like a different user.

You don't mention what OS you're using; file locations are different for each OS.  But if you've already found your profile, you're in the right place.  Of course, make these changes with Firefox closed; the profile is constantly being updated while Firefox is running.

The general structure is that under the `Firefox` folder is a `Profiles` folder that normally contains all of your profiles. The Firefox folder also contains a file named `profiles.ini`.  This is a text file that lists your different profiles and some settings for where Firefox should look for the profile and other basic profile information.

Each profile reference there includes the path to the profile, and an `IsRelative` setting (1 or 0) to indicate whether the path is a short version of the path relative to the `Firefox` directory.  This will typically be set to `IsRelative=1` and `Path=Profiles/profilename`, indicating that the profile is in the local `Profiles` folder.

You can move or simply copy the profile to another location.  Then edit `profiles.ini` to use `IsRelative=0` and `Path=fullnewpath/profilename`.

Comment: I did as said (with absolute path) and checked profile location with `about:support`. But DRM still does not work. I tried it just the same on another absolute path on c: and then it worked! **So the problem with drm not working only exists if the profile isn't on c: but on another drive**. So what do i need to additionally to change (some link or something) that drm also works?

Comment: @SearchSpace, that's an interesting discovery.  I'm not in a position to replicate it to figure out what might be going on.  The issue isn't the profile, itself.  Firefox doesn't care where it resides, as long as it knows where to find it.  It sounds like the problem is something related to DRM.  It may be a simple programming oversight (designed to look only on the same drive), or it might be intentional as part of the DRM restrictions.  I'm not that familiar with DRM operation.  Maybe someone else will be able to shed some light on it.